# SwiperJS start view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using SwiperJS (https://swiperjs.com/demos/#3D_cube_effect). The position forces a straight face to start. I would like this cube to be in this position:
[image: Attah]
I wish I could see two walls when scrolling, not one.

HTML

```
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.swiper-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -150px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

JS

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'cube',
  grabCursor: true,
  cubeEffect: {
    shadow: true,
    slideShadows: true,
    shadowOffset: 20,
    shadowScale: 0.94,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
  // autoplay:{
  //   delay:3000
  // },
});
```

Comment: Checked your code right now and it works. How do you connect plugin js and plugin css?

Comment: The slider works fine, but my point is that when you scroll, you can see two walls at the same time

Comment: I have given a solution. Was such a result necessary?

Comment: that is, it scrolled in the 3d effect so that you could see some of the second trace

Answer (score 0):

The css rule `rotateY` is responsible for the state of the rotation position. To redefine, add this jiquery code using **API** SwiperJS:

```
$('.swiper-wrapper').addClass('state');

swiper.on('touchMove', function() { 
  $('.swiper-wrapper').removeClass('state');
});
```

And add this to your css:

```
.swiper-wrapper.state {
  transform: rotateY(-45deg)!important;
}
```

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'cube',
  grabCursor: true,
  cubeEffect: {
    shadow: true,
    slideShadows: true,
    shadowOffset: 20,
    shadowScale: 0.94,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
  // autoplay:{
  //   delay:3000
  // },
});

$('.swiper-wrapper').addClass('state');

swiper.on('touchMove', function() { 
  $('.swiper-wrapper').removeClass('state');
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -150px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.swiper-wrapper.state {
  transform: rotateY(-45deg)!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.6/swiper-bundle.min.css" integrity="sha512-nDK7V7W9Sac8PVJy+hbDCe+b8XWbwrvigsWO943CfXexh2zIquVfEfVP9Cy5cbP+B5v/9lgxOAlp2yES7n/FIA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.6/swiper-bundle.js" integrity="sha512-AO8EjcB+txNbSKoPw/P1203KP3YPQ5YTNR+ndaZadfDEAXrLrg/dzLSFurI/XV9OkPy7AE9m+f0Shzfc+kVKvQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: all fine, but that's not the point. I would like the slider to look like in the second graphic "
this is how supposed to be" that is, it scrolled in the 3d effect so that you could see some of the second trace

Comment: @Simon, Do you want the two walls to be visible normally? Those. scrolled, and the cube took the position with the display of two walls. So?

Comment: yes, I want every one wall to be scrolled, but two walls are visible first

Comment: @Simon, I'm not familiar with this slider, but I figured out how to solve your problem. Give me a little time

Comment: Made it even better than it was before. Check

Comment: yes, the first view is ok now. But when scrolling, this view should be the same all the time, just swap the slides. You know what's going on?

Comment: @Simon, Hi. It was already late yesterday, I went to bed. Is your problem still relevant?

Comment: @s.kuznestov Can u help with solution?

Comment: @Simon, I will try to help.

Comment: @s.kuznestov 
what should i do? Your solution only works well in the beginning. The idea is to keep the 3D view while scrolling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227644/discussion-between-s-kuznetsov-and-simon).